# Apache ignores Document root

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration, virtualhost

I have the following VirtualHost file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias domain.com

        ServerAdmin michael@xxx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxx/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Apache seems to ignore my `Document Root` and shows me instead a file which is located in the

```
/var/www/html
```

directory. Is there anything I need to change in order to get this running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that this is the only virtual host that is on port 80. I suspect that another place will be overriding this.

Also there is no directive for the directory, so you may get permission issues when you do get it working.

Often I find other virtual hosts hiding in things like apache.conf.

Also you know that there are two places for the site files right? sites-available and sites-enabled. If it's not in sites-enabled it will do nothing. Use `sudo a2ensite siteName` to create a simlink to the file in sites-enabled.

Also if you are on Apache 2.4 the files will need to end in .conf to be picked up. Things changed a bit from 2.2 to 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1! It is, the file ends with .conf and is already simlinked with a2ensite to sites-enabled. It's quite a fresh installed server, so I don't think there is another vhost setup (I didn't do it and I'm the only one at this server.) Can you imagine anything else?

Comment: The point with the directive for the directory seems promising to me. What would be a way to set them?

Comment: You should have a directory defined as specified here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory. It also pays to set the security so if you want all to have access 'Require all granted'. I normally put that inside the vhost under the document root .

Comment: But you many want to grep your conf files for .80 something must be specifying another vhost. `grep -R 80 /etc/apache2/*`

Comment: The directory directive has done the trick, now it's working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that one should also look for directory directives in apache.conf and the like overwriting other directory directives.

Answer (score 5):

After spending over 30 min trying to figure out why stuff was being ignored it seems apache2.4 ignores your sites-enabled configs if they do not end in .conf for example:

Wrong:

```
ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
001-owncloud  002-owncloud-ssl  003-ram
```

Correct:

```
ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
001-owncloud.conf  002-owncloud-ssl.conf  003-ram.conf
```

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't gotten more upvotes. thank you.